# how to change date format to mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, model-view-controller

im gettin the date in this format "3/16/2017 10:53:44 PM", how to get date in this format "16/3/2017 10:53:44 PM"

```
sample data

    "timestamp":"2017-03-16T17:23:44.860Z"


desired op
                "16/3/2017 10:53:44 PM"
    code
     binModel.UpdatedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(bin.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();


    data type
      public String UpdatedTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: Find this C# [fiddle](http://rextester.com/NJNK64408) for your ref

Comment: Change date to string only if you want it to display on UI otherwise don't change the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or Try to parse the datetime.
For example

```
DateTime dateformat = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToDateTime(bin.timestamp), "dd/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
binModel.UpdatedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateformat,TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to string:

```
binModel.UpdatedTime = bin.timestamp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

For more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` has no display format.
Only string represnetations of DateTime does.
You can specify the desired format as a parameter in one of the the `ToString` method overloads of the DateTime struct:

```
 var s = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Now `s` contains the folowing string: `"23/3/2017 09:01:32 AM"` (my local time)

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not considered as high quality answers. Please consider to put more context around your answer or put it as an comment.